# jquery advice or help converting flash to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was task to convert a something like this [flash](http://mrdoob.com/projects/xmas2009/Main.swf) file into jQuery...

any help or advice? it should be html 4. I'm not new to jQuery so if you have links that I can use to help me build this would be appreciated..

thanks, 
Reigel

edit: update/progress

okay, as [jAndy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305000/jandy) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164061/jquery-advice-or-help-converting-flash-to-jquery/3164122#3164122), I found this for [rotating images](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html)

Comment: wow, I like the flash. With Jquery, we need to do a lot of coding to get such effect. If you want to do it anyway use .animate() and change the position and size of the images.

Answer (score 4):

First 10 seconds it's a nice watch, but every second beyond is boring.

To accomplish that just with `javascript / jQuery`, one would need to load & cache like 500 images. I'd create an object/class for each image which stores `coordinates`, `rotating angle`, `speed`, `img source` etc. and finally fire those into some animating object/class.

Looks very possible with javascript, but I guess just the `DOM` is too damn slow to handle this, so your only choice here can be `canvas`. Since you mentioned just to use `HTML4` I don't think this is a task which can be **fairly** done.

Actually I would recommend a library like `raphael` or `cakejs`, but again, all those are using `HTML5 canvas` to render images.